# How to download and install wannacry patch for small business windows 2011 standard

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, security, patch-management

I have a small business windows 2011 standard server. The auto update is not working somehow. I want to download the patch and install manually. I have a look at this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms17-010.aspx

It didn't say anything about my server. Could anyone help me out?

Update 1:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg697164(v=ws.11).aspx. small business win 2011 is based on 2008 R2. On this page: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms17-010.aspx I saw 4 security patch. For minimum, Do I install "March, 2017 Security Only Quality Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 for x64-based Systems (KB4012212)"??????? I am running out of space.

Comment: If you've installed all available updates from MS, it should already be installed. Check with this PS script: https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/4038-check-for-ms17-010-hotfixes-powershell-wannacry

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/159331/how-is-the-wannacry-malware-spreading-and-how-should-users-defend-themselves-f

Comment: I came to this link: https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=ms17-010. I didn't see anything about business windows 2011 standard server

Comment: Free up adequate space and install **ALL** available updates. To do anything less is negligent. There's no good reason/excuse for not keeping your systems fully patched.

Comment: It's so sad how many administrators only care about security updates when it's on a news. The rest of us have installed these patches two months ago, when they were released. We were sleeping well during the whole weekend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's incredibly sad how many administrators only care about security updates when it's on a news!

The rest of us have installed these patches two months ago, when they were released. Therefore, we were sleeping well during the whole weekend. The SMB vulnerability has existed all this time, and **the patch is released for the vulnerability, not for the WannaCry** ransomware attack exploiting it.

You are running out of space, but security updates are the last you would like to miss for saving it. **Configure your system for automatic updates.** You could remove something less vital, move something to another partition/drive, or simply upgrade your hardware. Even upgrading to a larger hard drive is a minor investment compared to costs caused by recovering from an attack.

Windows Small Business Server 2011 Standard is based on the Windows Server 2008 R2, so the 2008 R2 section on [MS17-010](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms17-010.aspx) is the correct information. Instead of direct patch for only this problem, Microsoft has [simplified servicing models](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/windowsitpro/2016/08/15/further-simplifying-servicing-model-for-windows-7-and-windows-8-1/) and currently releases a **Monthly Rollup** addressing both security and reliability issues and **Security-only update** that only include new security patches.

> Historically, we have released individual patches for these platforms,
>   which allowed you to be selective with the updates you deployed. This
>   resulted in fragmentation where different PCs could have a different
>   set of updates installed leading to multiple potential problems. - -
>   The new rollup model gives you fewer updates to manage, greater
>   predictability, and higher quality updates.

So, the [Security Only update for 2008 R2](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4012212) is perfectly adequate for addressing this particular problem.

Comment: Great answer, I guess no one could say better about sadness because of security caring.